# Downloading 16 Mb web page with curl and parsing content between <body> tags

Tags: php, curl

I'm building a PHP application which does a curl request to a number of different URL's. It's then attempting to parse the string of data returned by curl to extract everything in the `<body> </body>` tags. This is working absolutely fine for 99% of URL's.

However, one such URL is a page, which takes some time to load in a browser. Upon inspection I realised that the markup for the page is 16 Mb.

The settings I have for curl are as follows:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
if (!$data) {
    echo 'ERROR: Curl has reported an error: ' . curl_error($ch) . "\n";
}
return $data;
```

The error message I added for the `!$data` condition is not output - so my assumption is there are no errors from curl itself. I attempted to change `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` to 120 seconds (as opposed to 5) but this doesn't fix the issue.

When `$data` is returned to my script:

```
if ($data) {
    $body = '';
    preg_match("/<body[^>]*>(.*?)<\/body>/is", $data, $body);

    if (empty($body)) {
        echo 'WARNING: nothing found in <body> tag: ' . "\n";
        var_dump($body);
    } else {
        // Writing to file occurs here...
        // This bit works ok when $body is available.
    }
 }
```

It's showing me the warning message "WARNING: nothing found in  tag:" and the output from `var_dump($body)` is an empty array:

```
array(0) {
}
```

Does anyone know how I can further debug this, as I'm not sure where the error is originating? I have manually saved a copy of the web page and there are indeed a starting and closing `<body>` tag with lots of HTML in between.

My assumption is this is some problem due to the file size. The "average" file size on this application is about 1 Mb, and my script works perfectly with these files.

I am running this on a server from the cli, i.e. `php download.php` not through a browser.

Comment: can you please share the url whose markup is 16MB or approx i want to see and test

Comment: Probably invalid markup, but hard to tell if you don't provide is with hat target URL.

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/ALL/?uri=CELEX:32008R1272

Comment: its only about 2.6MB approx

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI No, it isn't. Save a copy of the markup as a web page and then look at the file size. It's 358,894 lines long, so unlikely to be only 2.6 Mb.

Comment: Yes it's 16 megabytes. however, enable gzip compression (`curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING,'gzip')`), and its compressed down to approx 906 kilobytes (just shy of 1 mb) to download. PS, to check the size of the webpage, you can do `curl --compressed http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/ALL/?uri=CELEX:32008R1272 | wc -c` - also note that you shouldn't actually explicitly say `gzip`, you should just give CURLOPT_ENCODING an empty string, and curl will automatically list all supported compression encodings (which typically is gzip and deflate - but it makes the code less error-prone)